# Boolean was not initialized, yet, I initialized it earlier in the code

Tags: boolean

On line 72, which is line `while(coltt=true)`, it states I haven't initialized it,

But I did on line 42, I have tried multiple different ways to initalize it from `boolean coltt = false;` , and yet somehow they have all failed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//import javax.swing.
public class gradebook
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        double avg = 0;
        double avg2 = 0;
        double avg3 = 0;
        double avg4 = 0;
        double avg5 = 0;
        double avg6 = 0;
        ArrayList<Double> CMGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> MXGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> KDGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> DKGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> KYGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> RYGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        testOrganizer t1 = new testOrganizer("ColtMan", avg , CMGrades );
        testOrganizer t2 = new testOrganizer("Max",avg2, MXGrades);
        testOrganizer t3 = new testOrganizer("Kaden",avg3, KDGrades);
        testOrganizer t4 = new testOrganizer("Derek",avg4, DKGrades);
        testOrganizer t5 = new testOrganizer("Kyle",avg5, KYGrades);
        testOrganizer t6 = new testOrganizer("Ryan",avg6, RYGrades);
        String[] choices = { "ColtMan-1", "Kaden-2", "Max-3", "Derek-4","Kyle-5", "Ryan-6" };
        System.out.println("Current Students in the JavaGradebook");
        for(String k: choices)
        {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
        System.out.println("Who would you like to choose?(Numbers coordinate to the people)");
        int c = x.nextInt();
        boolean coltt;
        boolean kaden;
        boolean max;
        boolean kyle;
        boolean ryan;
        boolean derek;
        if(c==1)
        {
            coltt = true;
        }
        if(c==2);
        {
            max = true;
        }
        if(c==3)
        {
            kaden = true;
        }
        if(c==4)
        {
            derek = true;
        }
        if(c==5)
        {
            kyle = true;
        }
        if(c==6)
        {
            ryan = true;
        }
        while(coltt == true)
        {
            System.out.println("What would you like to do for ColtMan? 1 for add grade, 2 for see grades, 3 for see average, and 4 for change name");
            int ch = x.nextInt();
            if(ch == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("What grade would you like to add? (Input a number/the grade they got)");
                double gradee= x.nextDouble();
                t1.addGrades(gradee);
            }
            if(ch==2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CMGrades.size(); i++)
                {
                    for(int j =0; j < CMGrades.size(); j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(t1.getGrades());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only assign it `if(c==1)`, so it's not definitely assigned.

Comment: You can't initialize in if statements. if none of the if statements is executed then you will not have initialized variable... and that is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `coltt` is indeed declared before, **not** initialized. You only initialize it inside an `if` statement. The compiler will complain because, if that condition isn't met, there's no way to know what would be the `boolean` value. Initializing those `boolean` variables (with `false` would be a good idea) would fix it.

Comment: @YikesSquadRed If you think I fully answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted. Cheers!